# Entity Framework/C#: multiple includes from string array?

Tags: c#, arrays, entity-framework, include

If want to use the `Include()` method on some Entity Framework selection (in order to avoid the 'Object as been disposed' exception).
But Include only accepts one string as parameter which means one include only.
To do multiple include, you must chain includes `.Include("something").Include("something").Include("something")`

But I would like my includes to come from a string array.

So what I would want to write is the equivalent of `.Include(array[0]).Include(array[1]).Include(array[2])...Include(array[n])`

(Where 'n' = array.Length - 1)

Of course I don't know in advance what will be in the string array.

But I can't find the correct syntax so far.
Thank you for your help

EDIT: Given the suggetions I've had so far, I'd say please be precise about type and avoiding null value problems and test it. So far no solution seems to work and I get lost in what I can and can't do with this or that type.

Comment: I think `.Include("something,something2,something3")` will work

Comment: @MehmetInce there is no overload of Include method accepting "string params"; thus it is not possible unless you explicity define that method.

Comment: @Mehmet: I've tried the comma seperation "Entity1.Entity1b,Entity2.Entity2b" but I get and error mentionning  "Entity1b,Entity2"

Comment: Never blindly chain includes. Do you know what they do to your query output? The output can grow exponentially depending on the multiplicity of the associations. More than three includes should be exceptional and well-considered.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `params string[]` which will make your code even clearer:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Include<T>(this IDbSet<T> dbSet, params string[] includes) where T : class
{
    foreach (var include in includes)
        dbSet.Include(include);

    return dbSet;
}
```

Then you can use it both ways:

```
.Include("NavProp1", "NavProp2", "NavProp3");
```

And:

```
.Include(new[] { "NavProp1", "NavProp2", "NavProp3" });
```

Comment: Problems: IDbSet has no Include(), DbSet does. The problem is that I want to end with a list + This doesn't persist the data I need any way. I though dbSet = dbSet.Include(include); but not the same type + Copy/pasting this method and running it generated a stackoverflow error that I could not exactly explain since a string is not string[] so it should no cause confusion, I renamed it IncludeArray to run it.

Comment: `IDbSet.Include()` is provided by `IQueryableExtensions`. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679233(v=vs.113).aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
    public IEnumerable<T> GetDataWithIncludes<T>(string[] includes) where T: class, new()
    {
        DbQuery<T> dbQuery = null;
        DbSet<T> dbSet = this.Set<T>();
        foreach (string include in includes)
        {
            dbQuery = dbSet.Include(include);
        }

        return dbQuery.AsEnumerable();
    }
```

Comment: As the other suggestions so far, this still didn't solve my problem. I first thought that the would be a problem with the null value if includes was empty, but apparently there is such a problem even if include is not empty.

Comment: @TTT can you clarify the issue? what is the exception?

Answer (score 0):

You can always chain them in a loop:

```
var query = DataSource.Select(...).Where(...); // as IQueryable<T>
foreach(string include in includes)
{
   query = query.Include(include);
}

return query.ToList(); // materialize
```

Comment: Sorry, I had selected this as the answer, but trying to make my own solution based on the 3 replyes, I realise the IQueryable<T> has no Include() method.

Answer (score 0):

To other people investigating this issue, I've came up with a solution by combining @haim770 and @daryal solutions. It extends a given Context DbSet asQueryble and updates a local variable and keeps appending, based on the `string[] includes` parameter

Extension Class

```
public static class Extensions
    {
        public static IQueryable<T> IncludeMany<T>(this DbSet<T> model, params string[] includes)
            where T : class
        {
            var modelQuerable = model.AsQueryable();
            foreach (var value in includes)
            {
                modelQuerable = modelQuerable.Include(value);
            }
            return modelQuerable;
        }
}
```

Implementation

```
public async Task<TestModel> GetData(Guid id)
        {
            var testModel= await context.TestModel.IncludeMany(
                    "xx",
                    "yy",
                    "xx.zz"
                    ).All();
            return testModel;
        }
```

I hope this helps people looking for answers, even though the question is a bit old.